# AWS Step function - The value for the field 'null' must be a STRING

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to invoke a step function through Lambda. And the lambda dumps an input json to step function.
Here is the input to the step function from Lambda -

```
{
  "name": "Add step to EMR cluster",
  "input": {
    "TransactionId": "c6a3ea17-db1b-11ea-bd00-a366cfd325b1",
    "FileName": "NEA_FINAL_08072020_20.txt",
    "BucketName": "catalyst-landing-stage"
  },
  "inputDetails": null
}
```

I am trying to dynamically populate the FileName from the input json using the below code -

```
{
  "Comment": "Running Catalist step on Amazon EMR",
  "StartAt": "Add step to EMR cluster",
  "States": {
    "Add step to EMR cluster": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::elasticmapreduce:addStep.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "ClusterId": "j-JMJL7M823WT6",
        "Step": {
          "Name": "Catalist_Step",
          "ActionOnFailure": "CONTINUE",
          "HadoopJarStep": {
            "Jar": "command-runner.jar",
            "Args": [
              "spark-submit",
              "s3://usercase1-test1/Code/Catalist_MemberExtract.py",
              {"FileName$.":"$.FileName"},
              "s3://usercase1-test1/yesterday.csv/part-00000-ec88bf25-cb22-42d0-b341-f68289ebc781-c000.csv",
              "s3://usercase1-test1/MemberExtract_QC_08042020"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

And I get the above error "The value for the field 'null' must be a STRING"... Any help is appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your `Args` section, change this:

`{"FileName$.":"$.FileName"}`

to this:

`"$.FileName"`

Amazon States Language (ASL) wants only strings in there.  This is how references to input values are done in ASL.  `$` references the execution context object, so in this case it's like saying `input.FileName`.

For a bunch of examples specifically related to EMR clusters, check out the
Step Functions Developer Guide [section](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sample-emr-job.html#sample-container-code-examples) with samples of similar container use-cases, or the [Blog Post announcing Step Functions EMR Integration](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-using-step-functions-to-orchestrate-amazon-emr-workloads/#:%7E:text=AWS%20Step%20Functions%20allows%20you,workflow%20automation%20to%20your%20applications.&text=Starting%20today%2C%20Step%20Functions%20connects,time%2C%20and%20optimizing%20cluster%20utilization.)

Comment: I think "$$" is used to reference the execution context, "$" is for the state input.